# SQL statement for printing title and count ID after joining two table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT b.post_title
     , a.post_id
     , Deriv1.Count
FROM  wp_posts b
    , wp_postmeta a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (    
   SELECT meta_value, COUNT( * ) AS Count
   FROM  wp_postmeta
   GROUP BY meta_value
   ) Deriv1 
ON a.post_id = Deriv1.meta_value
WHERE a.meta_value = 1
  AND a.meta_key = 'type-select' 
  AND b.post_status = 'publish'
  and post_type = 'car-cc'
```

Current problem of the `SQl STATEMENT` is when i supply `meta_value =1` it is fetching all values i.e. `post_id` which do not have `meta_value =1` is also listed.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1115a7/1

Comment: You have a product join; how are tables `wp_post` and `wp_postmeta` related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you're not joining on the wp_posts table and wp_postmeta table.  Add this to your WHERE clause:

```
AND a.post_id = b.ID
```

Alternatively, just do an INNER JOIN on the two tables:

```
SELECT b.post_title
     , a.post_id
     , Deriv1.Count
FROM  wp_posts b INNER JOIN 
        wp_postmeta a ON a.post_id = b.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (    
   SELECT meta_value, COUNT( * ) AS Count
   FROM  wp_postmeta
   GROUP BY meta_value
   ) Deriv1 
ON a.post_id = Deriv1.meta_value
WHERE a.meta_value = 1
  AND a.meta_key = 'type-select' 
  AND b.post_status = 'publish'
  and post_type = 'car-cc'
```

BTW -- Did you want the count for each group?  If so, your query can be simplified:

```
SELECT b.post_title, a.post_id, COUNT( * ) as Total
FROM  wp_posts b INNER JOIN 
            wp_postmeta a ON a.post_id = b.ID
    WHERE a.meta_value = 1
      AND a.meta_key = 'type-select' 
      AND b.post_status = 'publish'
      and post_type = 'car-cc'
GROUP BY b.post_title, a.post_id
```

Here is some updated [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1115a7/12).  Wasn't sure of your desired output.

Good luck.

Comment: Think's like you are an SQL GEEK. @sgeddes